# API Query Parameters

Tags: php, rest, curl, asp.net-web-api

This is my first time handling an API task. And I am really lost, I tried looking and reading in google but I find it hard to understand. All I can see is it should have this line of codes.

```
<?php
$data = '';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'GET https://private.com/mymusic?from=2012-09-04&to=2012-09-05');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{username}:{password}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',       
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))                                                                       
);  

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($output);
?>
```

so my question is how will I insert a query parameter there? example query is `unique_visitors`

I apologize if my question is vague or lacking information.

Comment: Are you talking about a `$_GET` query? In PHP you can simply store `$_GET` variables like `$output = $_GET['unique_visitors'];` See [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: I need to get some details in the site. If I'm deleting the `GET` i'm getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the query is `GET` type by default. No need to specify that.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://private.com/mymusic?from=2012-09-04&to=2012-09-05');
```

Now, adding more parameters
if it's a `GET` only API, which looks like that, but really unclear, you just add parameters to the URL, adding them one by one to URL separated by `&` symbol, like:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://private.com/mymusic?from=2012-09-04&to=2012-09-05&unique_visitors=1');
```

Comment: well, I don't know what kind of API this is and its rules. You don't provide this info. All I can do is to judge by what you provided. Maybe it's a `POST` type of API? I don't know. Provide more data please